# Query for backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-string, sql-server-2014

I'm new to sql, and I'm trying to do a query for my backups, but I'm getting an error with some of the lines, I have 20 or more databases, but my query doesn't work on all the DB, its the same query for each DB, it display a message:

query:

```
USE [DB Name];
GO
BACKUP DATABASE DB Name
TO DISK = 'E:\xxxx\xx\DB Name.Bak'
   ;WITH FORMAT
      MEDIANAME = 'DB Name_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup DB Name'
```

Is giving the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 69
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DB Name'.

What am I doing wrong? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post the list of DB Names, with which ones work and which don't?

Comment: @carlos ortiz Please check my post

Answer (score 2):

Try using brackets around the second `[DB Name]` too and make a few syntax fixes to your command:

```
USE [DB Name];
GO

BACKUP DATABASE [DB Name]
TO DISK = 'E:\xxxx\xx\DB Name.Bak'
    WITH FORMAT
    , MEDIANAME = 'DB Name_SQLServerBackups'
    , NAME = 'Full Backup DB Name';
```

*(this worked for me)*

Comment: thanks for the info! ill keep you posted on how it went!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best place to start would be with the scripts put together by [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) which are very comprehensive and cover everything you will need.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest getting in to Ola's scripts, especially if you don't have the fundamentals down yet. Also, I think too many people are dependent on other peoples work, like Ola's scripts. I would work on the basics and then write your own scripts, to do exactly what you need them to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE master
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012.bak' 
 WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT,
 NOINIT,  
 NAME = N'AdventureWorks2012-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO

--SPlit backup Process

USE master
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012_1.bak' 
,DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012_2.bak' 
,DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012_3.bak' 
,DISK = N'D:\Backup\AdventureWorks2012_4.bak' 
 WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT,
 NOINIT,  
 NAME = N'AdventureWorks2012-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that will backup all databases on your server. I would look carefully at this and learn exactly what it is doing. It's a good starting point but I would try to work to create your own scripts, what works best for you. The cursor allows you to iterate through all the databases and STATIC ensures you capture all databases when querying sys.databases.

```
/* Full database backup for all user databases. */

DECLARE @dbname    varchar (300)
DECLARE @filepath  varchar (1000)
DECLARE @filedate  varchar (20)
DECLARE @filename  varchar (256)
DECLARE @subdir    varchar (1000)

SET @filepath = 'C:\TestBackup\' --This is your backup directory
SET @filedate = REPLACE(GETDATE(), ':', '_') --CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) --gets the date and timestamp, replaces : with an underscore

DECLARE backup_cursor CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
SELECT [name]
FROM master.sys.databases sd
-- WHERE ... exclude databases

OPEN backup_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM backup_cursor INTO @dbname   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

SET @subdir = 'C:\Backup\' + @dbname
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @subdir  

       SET @fileName = @filepath + @dbname + '\' + @dbname + '_' + @fileDate + '.bak'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @dbname TO DISK = @fileName
       WITH CHECKSUM, STOP_ON_ERROR
       RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = @fileName
       WITH STOP_ON_ERROR

       FETCH NEXT FROM backup_cursor INTO @dbname 

END   
CLOSE backup_cursor   
DEALLOCATE backup_cursor
```